# Check if asyncio shielded coroutine ran

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

If I have the following code sample

```
async def coro():
    # Cancelled error could be raised here
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # Or here
    await asyncio.shield(
        another_coro()
    )
    # Or here

async def wait_on_it(loop):
    f = loop.create_task(coro())
    # Pretend f may or may not happen, I just sleep in this example
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if not f.done():
        f.cancel() # Will raise CancelledError when some await finishes in coro()
```

How can I determine whether or not the shielded task actually ran? I have important logic that must be run iff the shielded task did run. Maybe shielding that function is not the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coro()` can transfer the information to the caller by modifying a mutable object it receives from the caller:

```
class Ref:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)

async def coro(run_ref):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    run_ref.ran_another_coro = True
    await asyncio.shield(another_coro())

async def wait_on_it(loop):
    run_ref = Ref(ran_another_coro=False)
    f = loop.create_task(coro(run_ref))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if not f.done():
        f.cancel()
    if run_ref.ran_another_coro:
         # ... another_coro() was started
```

Since `asyncio.shield` can't suspend, if `wait_on_it` observes a true value of `run_ref.ran_another_coro`, then `another_coro()` is guaranteed to have been started.

Comment: Is there a reason you define class `Ref` instead of simply using a bool?

Comment: @shane Yes, a `bool` is not mutable. Assigning to a `bool` inside a function would only modify the local variable, not the variable in the caller. On the other hand, assigning to a slot of a mutable object provided by the caller will change the object, which is seen by both `coro()` and its caller.